# If Customer Has Never Bought, Add Product to Cart - Code Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement a function that will check if a customer has ever bought ANY product from my shop before, and if not - provide them with a free "sign-up gift" on first purchase.

I am able to automatically add the product to the cart fine enough, but the issue occurs afterwards - the product keeps getting added to the cart even after a customer has made a purchase.

Code below - can't figure what the issue might be.

```
function has_bought( $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
    " );

    // Count number of orders and return a boolean value depending if higher than 0
    return count( $results ) > 0 ? true : false;
}

function aaptc_add_product_to_cart() {
    if( ! has_bought() && ! is_admin() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $product_id = 2449;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
        $found  = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }    
}

add_action( 'init', 'aaptc_add_product_to_cart' );
```

**** EDIT ****

Based on the support provided I have some new code that auto-adds the product to the cart, checks for orders and removes the product if orders exist.

Can someone please confirm whether the code below is correct?

```
/*
* Automatically add product to cart
*/
function insta_add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 2449;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
        $found  = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }    
}
add_action( 'init', 'insta_add_product_to_cart' );

function remove_shirt_returning_customer() {
    $product_id = 2449;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // Get orders by customer.
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $user_id,
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    if ( !empty($orders) ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $product_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_shirt_returning_customer' );
```

**** EDIT ***

**THE SOLUTION**

So the previous code still gave me errors. What seems to work effectively (in my localhost environment) is the code below.

```
/*
* Automatically add product to cart
*/
function insta_add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 51;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
        $found  = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }    
}
add_action( 'init', 'insta_add_product_to_cart' );

/*
* Remove item from cart if previous order exists
*/
function remove_shirt_returning_customer() {
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
            $product_id = 51;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            // Get orders by customer.
            $args = array(
                'customer_id' => $user_id,
            );
            $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                 if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id && !empty( $orders ) ) {
                      WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
             }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_shirt_returning_customer' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that custom query try using the `wc_get_orders` function you can retrieve all the orders from a customer using the `email address` or the `user id`

```php
// Get orders by customer with ID 12.
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => 12,
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

More info about the `wp_get_orders` can be found [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

Comment: But I would need the script to check every customer. The code is for every customer across the board. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, just change the number 12 for your variable `$user_id`

Answer (score 0):

You're only going to be able to tell whether the user has ordered from you before or not if they are logged into an account. So if the user is on your site and is logged into the account, you will have to find out [which user](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_user_id) that is:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

From there use Enrique's answer to obtain whether that customer has placed an order with you or not.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => 12,
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

From there, test whether `$orders` is empty or not, if empty leave the item as a default in the cart, if not remove it.

A better approach would be to just automatically have the item in all carts, then conditionally check whether this user is logged in, and has placed an order with you before. If so, remove the item.

Comment: Based on your's and Enrique's replies I have updated the code do do as you suggested. Mind taking a look and letting me know if anything seems incorrect? Should this work? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah i mean it looks good, but you'll need to test it on your dev environment and see what happens. Do that and post in the question again your results if it isn't working.

Comment: It didn't work, but I managed to do some tweaking which seems to work effectively now.

Have a look and let me know if anything seems wonky (hate scrappy code, but I'm not the best programmer - all help appreciated).

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Yeah one other thing is you might want to consider using a different hook than `init`, I typically don't use `init` as an action hook. I'm assuming you're building this in a plugin? It's not terrible to use `init` but it might lead to some complications if it's ran before other WP and WC processes. Check out the reference and see if you can find another one that would still initialize it early enough, you just want to make sure your code isn't loading before any core WP or WC code: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/

Comment: Other than that it looks good and if it's working on your test environment you're at least on the right path.